# Horizontal div scroller with enlarge on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, scroller

I'm wondering if someone could help. I'm trying to create a horizontal scroller activated by mouse, which enlarges div on hover. But can't get it working.

I have created an example here: http://vonholmes.co.uk/scroller/scroll-test.html

However, the 6th element in the list doesn't display at all & the 5th goes erratic on hover!

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this or some way to fix my code?

Have also tried using: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#quickdemo - but enlarging on hover also causes this to break.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a small change in your jquery animate function and now it is working fine for me.
Issue was with the width allocated to li tag.

```
$("ul li").hover(
function(){ 
$("ul li").animate({'width':'100px'},'fast');   
    $(this).animate({'width' : '250px'},'fast');
},
function()
{
    $(this).animate({'width':'130px'},'fast');
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This does make it function correctly, but is there a way of keeping the width at 130px, and only enlarging it? This method resizes everything to 100px, apart from the current one.

Comment: In that case i would suggest you a work around - i removed the additional jquery line i added previously and added two more li with visibility as hidden, for my surprise it is working like a charm.           <li style="visibility:hidden;">    </li>
<li style="visibility:hidden;"></li>